# What is the numerical type I can use in go to get the largest number?

Tags: go

Assuming the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var MaxInt uint64
    MaxInt = 1<<64 - 1
    fmt.Printf("Type: %T Value: %v\n", MaxInt, MaxInt)
}
```

I get the results of:

```
Type: uint64 Value: 18446744073709551615
```

Just as expected.

However, say I want to get a larger, say `1<<256 - 1`, when I use

```
func main() {
    x:= 1<<256-1
    fmt.Printf("Type: %T Value: %v\n", x, x)
}
```

I get:

```
./prog.go:10:10: constant 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936 overflows int
```

For `x:=1<<512-1` I get:

```
./prog.go:10:10: shift count too large: 512
```

My question is: What types can I use go to play with large numbers at this scale?

Comment: `big.Int` https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/

Comment: „The largest number“ would be something asserted by I0. This is probably too big gor your nerds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [math/big](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/) package. It contains types Int, Float, Rat (rational).